# Is __CHAR_BIT__ macro predefined for MSVC compiler?

Tags: c++, macros

Is `__CHAR_BIT__` macro predefined for MSVC compiler? How do I know the list of predefined macros available for a compiler?

Comment: `__CHAR_BIT__` is not predefined by MSVC, nor (AFAIK) any other compiler.   But is an identifier that the standard reserves for use by the implementation, even if any particular implementation doesn't use it.  `CHAR_BIT` is defined in the standard header `<climits>` and (for C compatibility) `<limits.h>` with an implementation defined value.  Read documentation (or the standard) to find what predefined macros are specified in the standard.   Read documentation for your compiler to find what macros it defines.

Comment: I think that's an answer @Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler's documentation will give a list of predefined macros. In the case of MSVC, that's [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019). All macros which are specified in the standard will still be available, as long as you include the appropriate header (and in some cases if you include some other header).

In the case of `__CHAR_BIT__`, that's not part of the standard; the `CHAR_BIT` macro is, and is declared in the header `<climits>`. I rather doubt that MSVC has `CHAR_BIT` or `__CHAR_BIT__` as a predefined macro: that compiler mostly uses predefined macros to provide access to compilation flags, and instead defines architecture-dependent macros directly in the headers (of course, using predefined macros to determine what architecture that is).

I suppose to check whether a macro is *predefined* rather than defined in a header, you'd just check before including any headers. I can't think of a reason you'd want to do this, though.